# Sending data to servlet over httpo using java DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, http, endianness

I am sending some binary data ([byte[]) (using the java DefaultHttpclient) to the servlet running on a apache tomcat server. My question is do I need to worry about machine endianness before sending data to the server. Does DefaultHttpClient automatically take care of converting data to network byte order ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using Java on both ends, and HTTP on the wire, so you don't have to worry about endian issues.  You do have to encode your byte array, of course.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by encoding ? Thanks